# tImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

```
07-17 15:51:16.429: D/visibility(10457): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-17 15:51:21.339: D/visibility(10457): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-17 15:51:32.309: D/visibility(10457): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-17 15:51:40.604: D/visibility(10457): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

My Codes:

```
try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String jsona = json.getString("Email");
                    if (jsona == null) {
                        goodrating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        badrating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        goodrating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        badrating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("visibility", e.toString());
            }
```

**THESE CODES ARE IN ASYNCTASK DOINBACKGROUND**
so why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing you code to:

```
try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String jsona = json.getString("Email");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (jsona == null) {
                        goodrating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        badrating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        goodrating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        badrating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("visibility", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: why do you need two `runOnUIThread` ? One should be enough and you can check the condition inside the same.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, that will also do.

Comment: you should use publishProgress instead. that's what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are updating ui from a background thread which is not possible. You must update ui on the ui thread. Use `onPostexecute`. The result of `doInbackground` computation is param to `onPostExecute` . So return result in `doInbackground`. Based on the value returned update ui in `onPostExecute`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Check the topic under **The 4 steps** in the above link

You can also use `runOnUiThread` to update ui (change visibility).

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void ... params) {

    return jsona ;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
             if (result == null) {
                    goodrating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    badrating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    goodrating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    badrating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
}
```

Comment: probably change the view's visibility?

Answer (score 0):

You must touch your views in

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         // Touch your views
     }
```