# Start thread in OnClick in an adapter Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-adapter

in my application I have an adapter with a button. In onclicklistener of this button I must to start a thread that modify the UI, but i receive an error. The code is:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailnews_layout, parent,
                false);
holder.commentButton = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButtonComment);
convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
final View commentView=convertView;

holder.commentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (menuPosition == false) {
                holder.commentsLayout.animate().translationY(-950)
                        .setDuration(2000);
                Runnable commentsRun = new CommentThread(position, commentView, holder);
                new Thread(commentsRun).start();
                menuPosition = true;
            } else {
                holder.commentsLayout.animate().translationY(-0)
                        .setDuration(500);
                menuPosition = false;
            }

        }
    });
public class CommentThread implements Runnable {
    private int position;
    private View convertView;
    private ViewHolder holder;

    public CommentThread(int position, View convertView, ViewHolder holder) {
        this.position = position;
        this.convertView = convertView;
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    public void run() {

        ...
    }

}
```

But I have this error:

```
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-97
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1440)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.app.FlipAdapter.addItem(FlipAdapter.java:447)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.app.FlipAdapter.access$2(FlipAdapter.java:422)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.app.FlipAdapter$CommentThread.run(FlipAdapter.java:551)
07-17 14:04:27.975: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The code in the run method of thread it's ok and work well out of onClick method. How con I change my code? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700401/timplcalledfromwrongthreadexception-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-vi/17700626?noredirect=1#comment25794488_17700626. similar post posted few minutes back

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the UI off of the UI thread which is why you are seeing the error saying

`android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

if you need to do a long running process or something before you update the UI you need to call back to the main thread either by using a `Handler` or using the methond `runOnUiThread`

Answer (score 0):

you can use runOnUiThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //some jobe
            }
        });
```

If you want update UI after some complex job use AsyncTask and update UI onPostExecute